# Import scikit in C# application

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, ironpython, scikit-learn

I am trying to import scikit-learn in a C# (console) application. I am using Python Tools for Visual Studio and IronPython 2.7.3.

I managed to run an external python script and I also managed to import numpy by declaring the python path: "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\"

However, when it comes to scikit-learn I get an error message:

```
Oops! We couldn't execute the script because of an exception: No module named _c
heck_build
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\__check_build:
setup.py                  setup.pyc                 setup.pyo
_check_build.pyd          __init__.py               __init__.pyc
__init__.pyo
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

The file "_check_build.pyd" exists in "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sklearn__check_build\".

My code is based on this article: http://devleader.ca/2013/09/23/visual-studio-c-python-sweet/
The file I am using has only the following code:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

print('Hello Python in C#')
```

Is it possible to add and use scikit in C#? If yes, could you please provide a workaround?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scikit be used from IronPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171923/can-scikit-be-used-from-ironpython)

Comment: I think you are right, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like scikit-learn requires a C extension, which means it won't run under IronPython.