# Building Python packages succeeds, but Scikit-learn is improperly built

Tags: android, python-2.7, scikit-learn, kivy, buildozer

I created an app using Scikit-learn and Kivy and it was built with Buildozer.

This is the code of **main.py** :

```py
# coding=utf-8

import kivy
import sys
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        try:
            from sklearn import svm, datasets
        except:
            return Label(text=str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
        else:
            return Label(text='Scikit-learn OK')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I specified Scikit-learn in the requirements in **buildozer.spec** :

```
[app]

title = Kivyris

package.name = kivyris

package.domain = org.test

source.dir = .

source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

version = 0.1

requirements = kivy,numpy,scipy,scikit-learn

orientation = landscape

fullscreen = 1

log_level = 2

warn_on_root = 1
```

I ran `buildozer android_new debug deploy run` (no error, APK file created and deployed) but I have the following error when the app is launched :

> Cannot load library:
>
> ---
>
> Contents of /data/data/org.test.kivyris/files/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/**check_build:
>   __init**.pyo               setup.pyo               _check_build.so
>
> ---
>
> It seems that sckikit-learn has not been built correctly.
>
> If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget to build the package before using it; run `python setup.py install` or `make` in the source directory.
>
> If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your Python version, your operating system and your platform.

On Windows and Ubuntu using `python main.py` it works well :

> Scikit-Learn OK

I installed Scikit-learn using `sudo apt-get install python-scikits-learn` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This is some informations from the device on which I ran the app :

- import platform failed; platform.platform() : I couldn't get this info (app failed to launch), but it's an Android 5.1.1
- import sys OK; sys.version : 2.7.2 (default, Mar 6 2017, 06:05:36) [GCC 4.8]
- import numpy OK; Numpy.**version** : 1.9.2
- import scipy OK; Scipy.**version** : 0.18.1
- import sklearn : error (see above).

I tried a few things unsuccessfully, so I looked online :

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240239/building-python-packages-succeeds-but-package-is-improperly-built/240260 : didn't work for me.
- [Import scikit in C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036793/import-scikit-in-c-sharp-application) : not really what I was looking for.
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/433 : works for Mac, not for Ubuntu.
- [Cannot import Scikit-Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464445/cannot-import-scikit-learn) : scipy works for me.

I didn't find anything useful and I have no idea how to solve that. Any idea please ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you wanna do that? the built `apk` file is about 70mb due to scipies huge size.

Comment: I have a Python application using a SVM that I am trying to migrate to Android. Since it uses Scikit-learn (and the iris dataset), I thought it could be a good idea to use Buildozer.

Comment: of course its a good idea but it would be so heavy. I suggest you develop a rest API to do the calculation for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to build your app for Android with module that uses pure Python, everything is ok: this module would be run by Python interpreter built for Android and shipped with your app.

Things much worse when your trying to build app for Android with module contains C extension or dependencies with C extensions (such as Scikit-learn). On Windows or Linux C Extensions [would be](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html) compiled using distutils, but for Android it's problem: C Extensions can't be compiled this way.

python-for-android handles this problem [providing](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/) mechanism of recipes:

> recipe: A recipe is a file that defines how to compile a requirement.
>   **Any libraries that have a Python extension must have a recipe in p4a,**
>   **or compilation will fail.** If there is no recipe for a requirement, it
>   will be downloaded using pip.

You can see list of existing recipes [here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes). As you can see no one did one for Scikit-learn, so I assume it can't be build for Android right now.

You can try to [create recipe](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/#creating-your-own-recipe) for this module manually or ask someone to help in [kivy Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kivy-users). Note, that it's probably not trivial task.