# Can scikit learn be used from IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, scikit-learn, ironpython, python.net

I have a model built in python. I have a C# Web application in which i want to score the records on demand. I am looking into option available to do so. 
What are my options to do integrate python scoring code in .Net (I really dont want to host a separate webservice)

PS: I am aware of the duplicate. [DUPLICATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171923/can-scikit-be-used-from-ironpython)
The question is 2 years old. I tried reaching out to people who answered the question, but i havent got a response to my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Many programming languages allow to invoke the process. So this can be one of your options. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11779143/1090562) with an excellent answer (whose code I took) for more details:

```
private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
{
     ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
     start.FileName = "my/full/path/to/python.exe";
     start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
     start.UseShellExecute = false;
     start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
     {
         using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
         {
             string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
             Console.Write(result);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that the correct answer to "can I use X in Y" is "yes of course you can use python library X inside of c#, simply use subprocess!"

Comment: Thanks for the response. Having a python engine in the application is a solution. However, I am looking for a less expensive apporach like ironpython etc. I am not sure if scikit is supported yet.